# How to add values from multiple JSON object and store the value in another JSON object in Angular 6

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, ionic3, angular6

I have two different JSON object. One object is empList and other one is holidayList.
I want to add hours from each JSON object.Andthe sum of hours should be pushed to sumHoursList JSON object.I am doing this using Angular6.
I am not getting exactly how to iterate this to get the required result.
**Basically I want to add hours from both the datalist of empList , to that want to add hours from holiday list, and the sum value should
append in sumhourlist**

Below is my code.

```
this.empList = [
      {
      'id': 1,
      'name': 'Name1',
      datalist: [
        {
          "date": 1,
          "hours": 6
        },
        {
          "date": 2,
          "hours": 0
        },
        {
          "date": 3,
          "hours": 12
        }
      ]
      },
      {
        'id': 2,
        'name': 'Name2',
        datalist:[
          {
            "date": 1,
            "hours": 0
          },
          {
            "date": 2,
            "hours": 8
          },
          {
            "date": 3,
            "hours": 0
          }
        ]
      },
    ];

    this.holidayList=[
          {
            "date": 1,
            "hours": 0
          },
          {
            "date": 2,
            "hours": 8
          },
          {
            "date": 3,
            "hours": 12
          }
        ]

   sumHoursList = [
     {
            "date": 1,
            "hours": 6
          },
          {
            "date": 2,
            "hours": 16
          },
          {
            "date": 3,
            "hours": 24
          }
   ]
```

Can anyone please help me how to do this.

Comment: its not entirely clear to what you want to append hollyday as it doesnt contain a datalist like emp

Comment: The structure is same like holidayList , as it is there in dataList of empList

Answer (score 0):

This is how I understand the question. You want for each date add the hours together. With this loop you emp array can contain a dynamic number of datalists.

```js
let sum = holidayList
empList.forEach((emp) => emp.datalist.forEach((obj, i) => sum[i].hours += obj.hours))
console.log(sum)
// output: [{ date: 1, hours: 6 }, { date: 2, hours: 16 }, { date: 3, hours: 24 }]
```

*Please also note that these are not JSON objects. They are JavaScript objects.*

Comment: if we are doing like this 'let sum = holidayList'. What if i have one more object same like holidaylist. suppose that is vacationlist.
Then how to do the same solution over there. @The Fool

Comment: And I want to do all this in input onblur method. Can we get the same result if doing in (ionBlur)?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you need to sum the hour values of all entries with the same date and it's irrelevant in which source they are located.

Basically you could do it like this (not the most efficient way but to give you an idea):

```
// map sources into a unified data structure
const extractedArraysFromEmpList = emplist.map((entry)=>entry.datalist)
const sources:Array<Array<{
  date:number,
  hours:number
}>> = [...extractedArraysFromEmpList,holidaylist];

// now reduce the various sources into one summed array
const result = sources.reduce((reducer:Array<{date:number,hours:number}>, singleSourceArray)=>{
  singleSourceArray.forEach((item:{date:number,hours:number}) => {
    const existingEntry = result.find((summedItem)=>summedItem.date===item.date);
    // if a entry with matching date already exists, sum hours
    if(existingEntry) existingEntry.hours += item.hours;
    // if no entry exists, add it.
    else result.push({date:item.date,hours:item.hours})
  }
}, [])

// result is sumHoursList
```

Note that code is untested. But it should give you an idea of how to solve this case.